# MODX Login Chunk for isLoggedIn

Tags: authentication, modx

I am using isLoggedIn Script for a members only site. It seems to work nearly perfect besides one thing: I am using the normal Chunk (lgnLoginTpl) which comes with the complete Login package. There in the form an action with an url/domain etc. is needed but i need it dynamic. This means if you enter an protected page you are redirected to login and after logging in back to protected page. I have more than one protected page so it must be some kind of "intelligent". 
&redirectToPrior=`1` is also not working in this case.

Can anybody help and tell me how to set up lgnLoginTpl correctly to get isLoggedIn script to work as I need?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first part of your problem, redirecting to login page when needed, is solved simply by setting the correct "unauthorized page" in your system settings. &redirectToPrior should be what you need, by *"not working in this case"*, do you mean it's not working at all or not redirecting back to the previous page, regardless of what it was?

If it is the fact that it simply isn't working, thats probably because it relies on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, ie a php server variable telling the page which page redirected to it. This will however not always be set depending mostly on browser. A workaround i've implemented is to place a little snippet at the top of the **Unathorized** page

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

This will "manually" set the HTTP_REFERER to the **current** URL, which is what you want, as the URL doesn't change after you've been redirected from a protected page to the unauthorized URL. And then you can use the &redirectToPrior param of the `Login?` snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I tried some things and I now it seems I have only one problem which is that I am redirected to unauthorized page (login page), that works fine but after logging in I am not redirected to the right protected page.

I made to different pages test1 and test2. If I am loggin in I am always redirected to test1.

test1 login -> test1

test2 login -> test1

It seems &redirectToPrior=1 is overriden by &loginResourceId=`12`. I am calling the plugin with following code:

```
[[!Login? &loginTpl=`lgnLoginTpl` &logoutTpl=`lgnLogoutTpl` &errTpl=`lgnErrTpl` &logoutResourceId=`0` &loginResourceId=`12` &redirectToPrior=`1`]]
```

Removing &loginResourceId=`12` (ID 12 is test1) doesn't work at all and redirects my to my 404 page (home).
&loginResourceId=`12` should be removed but what to insert instead?